# Error While checking username and emails already exists in database or not in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

Here is my code. When I click the register button it shows me both error msg of `Email is already Registered` and `Username is taken` even if they are not existing in the database.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Close();
    }
    con.Open();
}       
protected void fname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo cI = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    TextInfo textInfo = cI.TextInfo;
    fname.Text = textInfo.ToTitleCase(fname.Text);
}
protected void lname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo cI = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    TextInfo textInfo = cI.TextInfo;
    lname.Text = textInfo.ToTitleCase(lname.Text);
}
protected void register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkemail() == false && checkuname() == false)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Users values('" + fname.Text + "','" + lname.Text + "','" + email.Text + "','" + uname.Text + "','" + password.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    if(checkemail() == true)
    {
        chkmail.Visible = true;
        mailerror.Text = "Email Address already Registered";
    }
    if(checkuname() == true)
    {
        chkuname.Visible = true;
        unameerror.Text = "Username is taken!";
    }

}
private Boolean checkemail()
{
    Boolean emailavailable = false;
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Users where emailId='" + email.Text + "'";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        emailavailable = true;
    }
    return emailavailable;
}
private Boolean checkuname()
{
    Boolean unameavailable = false;
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Users where username='" + uname.Text + "'";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        unameavailable = true;
    }
    return unameavailable;
}
```

What I want is that if existing email is given, then it should send an error message to the email.

If existing username is given then it should show the username error message.

If both things are existing in database then both errors should be displayed.

Comment: I guess you inserted the user & email into the database and then you are asking whether the information is present. Try to move the first if statement to the end of register_Click method.

Comment: Never store passwords, salt and hash them.

Comment: 99.9% sure this is just a learning project, but @Çöđěxěŕ is very correct. In any sort of environment, production or otherwise, always salt and hash.

Comment: @NickGasiaRobitsch very well could be, I'll comment about it when I see something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your logic with something like this:

```
    if(checkemail())
    {
        chkmail.Visible = true;
        mailerror.Text = "Email Address already Registered";
    }
    else if(checkuname())
    {
        chkuname.Visible = true;
        unameerror.Text = "Username is taken!";
    } 
    else
    {
        chkmail.Visible = false;
        chkuname.Visible = false;
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Users values('" + fname.Text + "','" + lname.Text + "','" + email.Text + "','" + uname.Text + "','" + password.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

This way only one message will be shown and when everything is good, the insert query will be executed.

I'm not a C# dev, but I bet your next step should be look to ways to use bind parameters on your  queries, so you don concatenate the user inputs directly on your query strings.

Comment: The string concantenation is sadly correct for this imlpimentation when supplying a text based sql command. There are ways to parameterize the request, but that requires significant changes to current implimentation. However, many prefer to use string interpolation in cases like this instead  as it is a bit more readable. ex: `cmd.CommandText = $"insert into Users values('{fname.Text}','{lname.Text}','{ email.Text}','{uname.Text','{password.Text}')";`

Comment: @Nick and still vulnerable to SQL injection. What if someone wants `Zu'ul` as username? The code will fail.

Comment: @CodeCaster True, and yes the single quote would break in sql. Really, this should all be sanitized long before this point. You would want to detect the single quote and escape it if you were doing text based sql. That being said, if this were a real env, this would (should) be handled differently. Answer was specific to question/examples supplied. Excellent points though!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider changing the code to something like the example below:

```
public enum FieldType
{
    EmailAddress,
    UserName
}

protected void register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!checkfield(FieldType.EmailAddress) && !checkfield(FieldType.UserName))
    {
        // Both email address and username are avialable
        // do some stuff
        return;
    }
    if(checkfield(FieldType.EmailAddress)
    {
        // Email address is taken
        // do some stuff
        return;
    }
    if(checkfield(FieldType.UserName)
    {
        // Username is taken
        // do some stuff
        return;
    }
}

private bool checkfield(FieldType field)
{
    string sql = string.Empty;
    switch(field)
    {
        case FieldType.EmailAddress:
        sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE emailId = @p;";
        break;

        case FieldType.UserName:
        sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username = @p;";
        break;
    }
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    switch(field)
    {
        case FieldType.EmailAddress:
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", email.Text);
        break;

        case FieldType.UserName:
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", uname.Text);
        break;
    }
    var rows = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if(int.Parse(rows.ToString()) > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Adding the enum allows you to call a single method and alter the statement depending on which parameter you want to query. Also, changing the SQL statement to return a count of matching rows rather than a data table is more efficient when you're not really interested in the results, just the number of matches. Adding a return after each of the statements in register_Click event handler prevents the code from moving on when one of the conditions is met, this way the user will only see the one message, not all of them. Hope this helps!